# How do I save list box items in text file in asp.net [server side]?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used 2 list box controls 
ex:

```
list box 1   list box 2
hi
bye
how
```

then pass values in 2nd list box
ex:

```
 list box 1   list box 2
  how          hi
               bye
```

I have code for  save a 2nd list box items int text file (Notepad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the ListBox and then write it to your txt file.

```
 string sListBoxItems = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
     sListBoxItems += listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
  }

File.WriteAllText("yourfile.txt", sListBoxItems );
```

Comment: List box count is "0" so loop not run

Comment: what you mean "count is 0"?  I can help you if you can explain your problem with details.

Comment: I'm pass values in 1st list box to 2nd list box . then save a 2nd list box but its empty

Comment: how do you pass values ? can you provide your code?

Comment: http://codedisplay.com/javascript-to-transfer-data-from-one-listbox-to-another-listbox-considering-postback-using-asp-net-c-vb-net/